# Datagrid column width (not autogenerated) don't change if datacontext changes

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtextcolumn

i have a wpf datagrid with several defined DataGridTextColumns. When i bind long strings (100 characters) the bounded column grows correctly depending on content. When the datacontext change and the bounded strings gets shorter (10 characters) the column width dont't shrink.

If the datagrid generates the columns (AutoGenerateColumn="True") the column width adjust correctly when the datacontext change.

How can i achieve my defined columns to adjust depending on her content?

Comment: Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560581/how-to-autosize-and-right-align-gridviewcolumn-data-in-wpf

Comment: @Silvermind that link is GridView and I think it also suffers from not giving back space.

Comment: I have seen this problem where you don't get space back.  Hopefully someone will have an answer for you.  What I do is use TextBlocks with wrap and a hard column width.

Comment: Did you explicitly set the Width to "Auto", just asking.

Comment: @Silvermind How would you set the width of DataGridColumn to Auto if AutoGenerateColumns = "True" ?

Comment: @Blam It's just there `<DataGrid ColumnWidth="Auto"/>` however i tested it already and it does not work resizing back.

Comment: Your question looks like this question btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725724/datagrid-column-widths-not-updating-on-itemssource-change