# Auto resize DataGrid column to content

Tags: wpf, datagrid, resize

When column width is set to auto in DataGrid, the column only seem to be able to grow, never shrink in size.

I would like the column to always resize to the actual content of the column.

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725724/datagrid-column-widths-not-updating-on-itemssource-change).

Except I would like the resizing to happens automatically when content changes, without having to explicit execute some code.

Also I would like it to be flicker free and fast or if I'm asking the impossible, then almost flicker free and fast at least :-)

I found a link which seems helpful, http://forums.silverlight.net/t/71184.aspx. But I can't find DesiredWidth property in the code...