# Change the column width according to the contents

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that his ItemSource binding to the following object:

```
public ObservableCollection<X> MyCollection{ get; set; }
```

Class X contains all the data to the DataGrid's columns

Example:

```
private string name;

public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        name= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

etc.

Is there anything I can to set in **xaml** to the width of the columns will be based on content (when the content will change the width will also change accordingly)?

I've seen a number of examples that do this in C# code, I want it to be done in XAML, is it possible?

**EDIT:**

DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.x}" Binding="{Binding X}"></DataGridTextColumn>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.y}" Binding="{Binding Y}"></DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: It expands the columns based on content, but when the content is less than width was before he does not reduces back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are explicitly defining your column in XAML like you are, just set the width to Auto. This should be the default though.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Name}" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I tried it, still remains the problem will not be a small width

Comment: Ok I understand your problem now. You want the column to shrink with the content as it becomes smaller. It looks like you are going to have to get down and dirty and introduce some code to do this for you unfortunately. See [DataGrid-Column widths not updating on ItemsSource change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725724/datagrid-column-widths-not-updating-on-itemssource-change)

Answer (score 5):

You can set `ColumnWidth="SizeToCells"` this will work.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DG" ColumnWidth="SizeToCells"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Avaliable size modes for `ColumnWidth`

- **Auto** The default automatic sizing mode sizes DataGrid columns based on the contents of both cells and column headers.
- **SizeToCells** The cell-based automatic sizing mode sizes DataGrid columns based on the contents of cells in the column, not including
  column headers.
- **SizeToHeader** The header-based automatic sizing mode sizes DataGrid columns based on the contents of column headers only.
- **Pixel** The pixel-based sizing mode sizes DataGrid columns based on the numeric value provided.
- **Star(*)** The star sizing mode is used to distribute available space by weighted proportions

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom though, this practice is not recommended cause it has performance issue, SizeToCells would wait all data to load then calculate the column width according to the longest one. so, be careful.

Comment: It still does not work,It expands the columns based on content, but when the content is less than width was before he does not reduces back

Comment: This should refresh alone when content changes?